# laravel 5,am I including too much libraries?

Tags: php, laravel, compilation, include

I am new to Laravel, and I have started working on Laravel 5.x( the current version on the question date). My app uses bunch of libraries, including [Amazon MWS library](https://github.com/przemekperon/amazon-mws-laravel),  [a parser](https://github.com/orchestral/parser) and many more, see this image for an idea[image]
these seems to be a lot of folder, and including Laravel Framework folder...
many of these built in options would never by used by me directly and intentionally..Also, say from a library, I would use only one method (tojson method from a lib for example)

Already admitted, I am new to Laravel, and from my native understanding, only parts of libraries are included when called..

So, my basic question is,

> When and HOW do you know you are including too much ?
>
> How you people manage this??

thanks...and sorry if my question seems offensive to anyone, I believe its directly relating to programming and will help many others like me too..

Comment: This is not a concrete after all. If you project is intended to load information about your mascots then you are overloading things, however if your projects is developed to take control of wall-street then you are justifying why too much libraries.  But there is not a point where people say "One more library and the project will be bad".

Comment: @manix I'm curious, who says this "One more library and the project will be bad"? And what's the logic behind the statement?

Comment: @manix I am curious too about it...

Comment: My language is poor or I assumed bad things. When I read the question I felt that the author was worried about including to much libraries, and he clarifies that is new with laravel. So, I am trying to let he knows that there is not a point where things get wrong or not based in the number on included libraries. In big projects is more easy justify the inclusion of tons on dependencies instead of small projects. Between them there is not exists any case to consider a bad o good project based in includes.

Comment: @manix Ok it's clearer now, thanks :).

Comment: @manix thanks and its ok...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There's no problem with including many libraries.**

Requiring and installing libraries doesn't create overhead in itself, as that code is executed only when you use it. Also most of the libraries in the `vendor` directory are Laravel dependencies.

If you [look at the framework's `composer.json` file](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/composer.json#L17-L42) and you'll see that Laravel already has a lot of dependencies as it uses a lot of Symfony components for the core, Monolog for logging, SwiftMailer for sending emails, and the list goes on:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "ext-mbstring": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "classpreloader/classpreloader": "~3.0",
    "doctrine/inflector": "~1.0",
    "jeremeamia/superclosure": "~2.2",
    "league/flysystem": "~1.0",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.11",
    "mtdowling/cron-expression": "~1.0",
    "nesbot/carbon": "~1.20",
    "paragonie/random_compat": "~1.4",
    "psy/psysh": "0.7.*",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "~5.1",
    "symfony/console": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/debug": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/finder": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "~1.0",
    "symfony/process": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/routing": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/translation": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2"
},
```

Just install whatever you need, there's no limit to how many libraries you use as long as your code is written properly.

Comment: +1 that was really helpful..thanks.. just waiting for other answers to come so that I may have more clear picture about the concept, though your answer suggests that my native understanding is quite ok...

Comment: You're very welcome. Using the libraries you need is just common sense, with the implied idea that you should not use more than one library that provides overlapping functionality, for example there's no sense in using SwiftMailer and PHPMailer in the same project since they both offer the same thing (but really this should make sense in itself :).

Comment: you are right and that makes a perfect sense, thanks again